# Codeigniter Login Setflashdata how to destroy

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Good evening everyone I would like to ask you who had an idea on how to destroy the flash data. when the user enters an invalid user and password. because when I refresh it will not be destroyed

Here is my validation code that will check if the user will enter an invalid password and checks the user type.

```
function validation()  
      {  
           $this->load->library('form_validation');  
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');  
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');  

           if($this->form_validation->run())  
           {  
               //true  
              $username = $this->input->post('username');
              $password = $this->input->post('password');

              $this->load->model('main_model');
              if ($this->main_model->can_login($username, $password)) 
              {
                  $usertype = $this->session->userdata('usertype');
                  if($usertype == "admin")
                  {
                     redirect('worklog/administrator');
                  }
                  else if($usertype == "staff")
                  {
                    redirect('worklogstaff/staff');
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username and Password');
                    return redirect(base_url().'login','refresh');
                  }
              }
              else 
              {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username and Password');
                 return redirect(base_url().'login','refresh');
              }
           }
           else 
           {
              
                $this->index();
           }


      }
```

So this is my view login view page.

```
<div class="login-page">
    <div class="login-box">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body login-card-body">
                <center><img class="mb-4" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/icons/ppanewlogo.png" alt="" width="200" height="200"></center>    <!-- /.login-logo -->
                <center><h1 class="h3 font-weight-normal text-dark">PRPO TRACKER V1.0</h1></center><hr>
                <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/validation" method="post">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" >
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('username')?></span>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3" id="show_hide_password">
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" >
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fa fa-eye" title="Show/Hide Password"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('password')?></span>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <div class="icheck-primary">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="remember">
                                <label for="remember">
                                    Remember Me
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row">
```

so this is my setflash data that will display when the user entered an invalid account but when i refresh it will not be destroy.

```
                    <?php echo '<label class="text-danger">' . $this->session->flashdata("error") . '</label>'; ?>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <p class="text-center text-muted">&copy; <?php echo "PPA PMO MO/C ADMIN " . date("Y"); ?></p>

            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: When you are refreshing the page are you also resubmitting the form?

Comment: how to determine sir ? sorry im just new at codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Flash session data will only be available for the next request and is then automatically cleared. You need to check your implementation.